# What are the benefits to purchasing the Cerberus Network for Mass Effect 2

Tags: mass-effect-2

I purchased ME2 used via Craigslist and do not have Cerberus Network access.  What are the benefits to having access?  I'm trying to decide whether or not to purchase access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It gives you access to some free (well, not REALLY free since you have to pay for it ;)) DLC's and possibility to buy others.

Here is a list of DLC's in ME2, the ones marked as "free" are available to any CN member.

http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Downloadable_Content

In my opinion - it's definitely worth it (especially for Zaeed, an additional squad member + nice side quest), and other DLC (the paid ones) are also very good, but play 2-3 hours and then decide.

Comment: So some DLC requires Cerberus Network access?

Comment: @M.Travis - *all* DLC requires Cerberus Network access from what I understand; it's how they authenticate any DLC you've installed. If you somehow manage to install DLC without purchasing it via the cerberus network, you'll get a message saying that the Network was unable to verify the following DLC: (lists DLC in question) and informs you that it won't be available during gameplay.

Comment: @Raven Dreamer is that true for Xbox 360?  It appears as though we can download the DLC from live.xbox.com without the Cerberus Network. http://marketplace.xbox.com/en-US/Product/Mass-Effect-2/66acd000-77fe-1000-9115-d802454108ce?DownloadType=GameAddon#LiveZone

Comment: @M.Travis - ultimately, I'm unsure, as I bought a new copy of the game.

Comment: So I bought Cerberus Network for Xbox 360 last night.  It cost 1200 Microsoft Points and it installed on my Xbox 360.  It does appear that Cerberus Network must be installed on your Xbox in order to play any of the DLC.  I didn't test playing the DLC without installing Cerberus Network though.

Comment: 1200 MSP? That's quite much, indeed. It sounds like purchasing a brand new ME2 copy could be a better deal, than getting it and CN separately. Well, now it doesn't matter anyway. CN is still a good thing, and all DLC's gathered together are making game about 20% longer, so you should consider trying them out too, eventually. Good luck!

Comment: Not all true. I got Kasumi with having the Cerberus network, and it worked. I think it only applies to the docs included with the Cerberus network.

Comment: DLC purchased off of XBLM should not require CN as there is as XBL can verify it. I don't know about DLC purchased from directly from [BioWare](http://social.bioware.com/user_entitlements.php) though.